# Does rent control apply to me between two 6-month leases (CA)?

Tags: california, rent

I am on a 6-month rental lease here in San Clemente, CA and just contacted my landlord saying I'm interested in signing another 6-month lease after this one ends (April 2021). She responded that I could apply to stay another 6 months, but they're increasing my rent by 31%.

I believe this property is rent controlled as described [here](http://www.swlaw.com/blog/real-estate-litigation/2020/02/06/a-landlords-guide-to-californias-new-statewide-rent-control-laws) and therefore can't be increased by more than 10% per year.

What I don't understand is whether rent control protects me from changes in rent between my current lease and a new lease, if I'm occupying continuously. Could someone clear that up for me, please?

Comment: My understanding is that in California, rent control is largely a matter of municipal statute, so the `california` tag may not be sufficiently specific.

Comment: I edited the question to include the city.